# Apps use same objects

Tags: app

When I create a new custom object, it can be used in many apps as defined. And the data of object can be shared. Can I restrict this object is only used by a specific app?

If not, please tell me why Salesforce allows object be used by many apps? Any document or article about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A App, is a set of tabs, the permisions about who can access to a object is defined by profile.

Answer (score 0):

Visibilty of tabs for an object in a particular app can be controlled with app settings but it goes for all profiles automatically.
Object level security can be controlled by Profiles of individual users and record level can be controlled with OWD(Organization wide default)
following links will be helpful:

```
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabsetsedit.htm&language=en_US
```

Record level permissions in salesforce is being controlled by OWD(organiztion wide defaults), where you can give access to a record in an object using role hierarchy or for special treatments for some particular users you can define sharing rules.

following link will be helpful in setting up OWD:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_security.meta/workbook_security/record_level_access_1.htm

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's right!

But profile only sets who can access, it cannot set the permission of record. That means everyone can see the data of object in other apps.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of adding this as an answer, why don't you either update your original question or respond to Toren's answer.  This sounds like a different question, so perhaps you're better asking a new question.  If Torsen's answer is correct, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: If you want controll who user access who record, you can do that by Sharing Rules. but it is for all the Org,